# Laravel 7 - Component without view

Tags: php, laravel, components, laravel-blade, laravel-7

I want to create a Component that provides only data without a view.

For example:

```
<x:wg.items.listing :items="$items->items()" :filter="$obj->settings['filter']">
    @foreach($items as $item)
        {{ $item->title }}
    @endforeach     
</x:wg.items.listing>
```

The Blade Component gets a collection of `:items` and a `:filter`.
Between the tags should be a filtered collection available.

Listing.php:

```
class Listing extends Component
{

    public $items;
    public $filter;

    /**
     * Create a new component instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($filter="0", $items="0")
    {
        $this->filter = $filter;
        $this->items = $items;
    }

    /**
     * Get the view / contents that represent the component.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\View\View|string
     */
    public function render()
    {
        $this->items = app()->make("App\\Http\\Controllers\\Frontend\\BlogController")->generateList($this->items, $this->filter);

        /*return view('components.wg.items.list');*/

    }
}
```

The `Listing.php` should not render a view, because so is the items collection only available in `components.wg.items.list` and not between the Blade x tags above.

Is that even possible?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do such a thing; Every variable you declare in the component is only available in the component itself.

... Unless you want to do it the **reeaally** dirty way. Then you can use global variables:

```
<x:wg.items.listing :items="$items->items()" :filter="$obj->settings['filter']">
    @php
        global $filtered_items;
    @endphp
    @foreach($filtered_items as $item)
        {{ $item->title }}
    @endforeach     
</x:wg.items.listing>
```

```
    public function render()
    {
        global $filtered_items;
        $filtered_items = app()->make("App\\Http\\Controllers\\Frontend\\BlogController")->generateList($this->items, $this->filter);

        return "{{ $slot }}";

    }
```

P.S: And btw, you should not put your filtering logic inside your controller. The model should be responsible for it.